# How to set the location of the reference section using the section-bibliography extension in quarto?

Tags: quarto

I am writing my thesis in quarto, and have a quarto book consisting of different chapters. Each chapter has its own reference section, which I've done using the section-bibliography extension. However, this places the reference section at the end of each chapter, while I would like to specify the location (e.g. before the supplementary results, after the discussion).

I have the following _quarto.yml file:

```
book:
  title: "booktitle"
  author: "My Name"
  chapters:
    - introduction.qmd
    - part: "Part I"
      chapters:
      - chapter_one.qmd
      - chapter_two.qmd
    - part: "Part II:
      - chapter_three.qmd
      - chapter_four.qmd

filters: 
  - section-bibliographies
reference-section-title: References
bibliography: references.bib
csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/springer-vancouver
format: docx
```

I've tried experimenting with the section-bibs-level setting but nothing seems to change, and the bibliography still ends up at the end of the document. I've also tried the :::refs::: command, but that also doesn't work. Is there a way to manually set the location?